# How to get cURL response from absolute URL by posting POST parameters to different website in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, post, http-post

I want to get response from the URL http://webcache.gmc-uk.org/gmclrmp_enu/start.swe by sending some POST parameters into it.
I have written a function as follows:

```
public function getResponse($params, $url)
{
    $post_data = '';
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $post_data .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }

    //create the final string to be posted using implode()
    $post_data = rtrim($post_data, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($post_data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

But, when I call this function as:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $params = array(
        "s_3_1_5_0" => "5205500"
    );
    $url = 'http://webcache.gmc-uk.org/gmclrmp_enu/start.swe';
    echo $this->getResponse($params, $url);
}
```

I am always redirected to the page: http://localhost:8000/gmclrmp_enu/start.swe
instead of getting response from the specified URL.
where, http:// localhost:8000/ is root URL of my local project.

How could I get the response from that URL and dump it?

Comment: a couple of bugs in your code. first off, rtrim will remove more than just the last & , meaning, if the last character in the last $value is a & , your last $value will be corrupted. further more, you're not properly url encoding $key , nor are you properly url encoding $value. best way to fix all of this: $post_data = http_build_query($params);

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got this response.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/gmclrmp_enu/start.swe" method="POST" name="RedirectForHost">
    <input type = "hidden" name="s_3_1_5_0" value="5205500">
    <input type = "hidden" name="SWEBHWND" value="">
    <input type = "hidden" name="_sn" value="QG3N3byeQ-lw2X0470Taoo2Mr1xU6fklSaK4bX.yXOH1DqcEpmRHVzctRxa1UYflcu-svwV7M0VFB6KvWmUEh4mUDGbJtaXeil1PnikFKVpr6fRP.i-GMhMRm41kZVFHaZA1QBjteOlfTXcwF0CLSh.MzwHUhdPVvYK9Ulfe.zCJQiSkU2XOt68YjT1lD-4jrTrIBzxJLUY_">
    <input type = "hidden" name="SRN" value="">
    <input type = "hidden" name="SWEHo" value="">
    <input type = "hidden" name="SWETS" value="1481276787">
</form>
<script language="javascript">
    var formObj = document.forms["RedirectForHost"];
    formObj.SWEHo.value=top.location.hostname;
    formObj.submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think you got response like this, and then javascript submitted the form to localhost:8000.

Comment: How did you know you got this response? Is there any way to submit the form to http://webcache.gmc-uk.org/gmclrmp_enu/start.swe and get response?

Comment: I ran it on command line(javascript doesn't work). You can check it on browser debugging tools too.